# TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable; disnake discord python problem

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, disnake

I'm writing a discord bot for my server, one of the functions is to create a channel when a member joins "Join to create channel" channel and move that member to his channel. I've used tips from this question: [Move member into voice channel discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63709483/20240411)
and my code rn looks like this

```
bot = commands.InteractionBot()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Индик's ready")
    guild = bot.get_guild(my server id)
    print(guild)

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if str(after.channel) == 'Join to create channel':
        if str(after) != str(before):
            await after.channel.clone(name=f'{member}s channel')
            channel = disnake.utils.get(disnake.Guild.text_channels, name=f"{member}'s channel")
            await member.move_to(channel)
```

The error i get is: **TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable**

I've also tried

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if str(after.channel) == 'Join to create channel':
        if str(after) != str(before):
            await after.channel.clone(name=f'{member}s channel')
            channel = bot.get_channel(disnake.Guild.text_channels, name=f"{member}'s channel")
            await member.move_to(channel)
```

But then i get:

```
channel = bot.get_channel(disnake.Guild.text_channels, name=f"{member}'s channel")
TypeError: get_channel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

I'm searching for a solution for a whole day, but still can't figure out why does this happen. Any tips? Any information will be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Which line of the code is the error originated from?

Comment: @msamsami line 36, **line 36, in on_voice_state_update
    channel = disnake.utils.get(disnake.Guild.text_channels, name=f"{member}'s channel") ...\disnake\utils.py", line 477, in get
    for elem in iterable:**

Answer (score 0):

Idk, I've found one Japanese site and there found that i can use

```
channel = disnake.utils.get(member.guild.voice_channels, name=f"{member}'s channel")
```

instead of

```
 channel = bot.get_channel(disnake.Guild.text_channels, name=f"{member}'s channel")
```

and it works!

Hopefully, this will help somebody